# Stipe Checkout not working in Safari (Works in Chrome)

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Im using Stripe checkout and all is working perfectly in Chrome but I can't understand why it isn't working in safari. Im getting a this warning in chrome

> [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 238ms

And this error in Safari

> Error: Checkout URL is malformed

```html
Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_API_KEY);

$price = Price::create([
    'unit_amount' => $unitAmount,
    'currency' => 'eur',
    'product' => $productId
]);

$checkout_session = Session::create([
    'line_items' => [[
        'price' => $price['id'],
        'quantity' => 1,
    ]],
    'client_reference_id' => $clientReferenceId,
    'customer_email' => $customerEmail,
    'mode' => 'payment',
    'payment_method_types' => [
        'card'
    ],
    'success_url' => "https://exemple.link.com/success.php?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}&parameter=".$redirectLink,
    'cancel_url' => $redirectLink,
]);


header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
header("Location: " . $checkout_session->url);
```

Comment: I'd start by applying proper URL encoding to the parameter values you are inserting into `success_url`.

Comment: Can you try using a simple URL (without interpolating a variable) as `success_url` and `cancel_url`? I suspect it doesn't like string interpolation there. I could be wrong. But a quick test should tell you.